# Create bluetooth NAP and PANU in PAN for Android and communicate with each other on basis of IP

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, pan

I am new to Android and Bluetooth. I am trying to set up a PAN network with PANU and NAP(GN) in the same using BNEP protocol of Bluetooth. My main intention is to make the a device make a NAP so that it can connect to TCP-IP and the other PANUs in piconet
will interact with the device in the NAP. I can use the Java reflection to support this. I am using android.bluetooth.BluetoothPan class for the connection as PAN. 
So I followed the steps in following sequence for set up:
a) I called the constructor for BluetoothPan and created the instance. [Object creation happens successfully with onServiceConnected() handler receiving profile value of 5]
b) I set the setBluetoothTethering() to true [After setting I check the status using isTetheringOn() function and the state is true]

So I think now this app will make the device work like a PANU ? Am I correct ? If no, what else I need to do ?
Now my question is how to make this application support NAP ? 
As Bluetooth Tethering is on, so is it already in NAP ?
If so, can I see the IP or port number for communication allocated to device when it is made to NAP. I cannot find a way for this.

My main intention is make a server device act like a NAP with some IP. and make some client devices with PANU, Now based on IP of NAP, I can run service discover in PANU side based on IP and interact.

Before, I had already set up communication between service and client using listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord() [Server] and listenUsingRfcommToServiceRecord() [Client] and many references in developer.android for setting up communication using this methods. That is very easy way to set up client-server communication and uses SDP. I am not using that here.

I want to do it through BNEP only

Note: After checking through ADB debugging I found that when it is connected to bluetooth tethering, the IP allocated can be seen by "adb shell ip route" and you can see the allocated IP for NAP in BT tethering. Now how to get this IP is my question or next task

Comment: I think that setBluetoothTethering() call will make it a GN/NAP in a piconet/PAN. But how to get the IP for the NAP.. as it is communicating through TCp-IP it should have an IP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I set up the tethering setBluetoothTethering() and make the PAN network  using the connect() apis I was able to set up the PAN.

After that as TCPIP communication was already happening, I checked the NetworkInterface and called getHostAddress() to get the IP info.

Comment: I have used reflection but its not working any other solution?